# Comparing the "sizes" of square roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\;x=3-\sqrt5,\;\;y=\sqrt5-2,\;\;z=5-2\cdot\sqrt5$.

How can I tell **without a calculator** which is the largest and which is the smallest, in value?

Comment: Estimating Sqrt[5] as 9/4 works (once you confirm the approximation is within 1/8 of the true value).

Answer (score 10):

For example (note that all involved numbers $\,x,y,z\;$ are positive!):

$$x>y\iff 3+2>2\sqrt5\iff 25>4\cdot5=20$$

and since the rightmost inequality is trivially true so is the leftmost one. Now you continue.

Comment: I am thinking of a geometric approach, Don. However you did it enough +

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

By squaring: for example
$$x>y\iff 3-\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{5}-2\iff5>2\sqrt{5}\iff25>20\quad{\text{true}}$$